# Porque sale mensaje de error: "Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'."

Tags: javascript, vue.js, typescript, vuex

[image: image of the error]

Estoy usando vuex para manejar el estado de mi aplicación. La aplicación está en Vuejs usando typescript.
Cuando quiero insertar algunos datos en un array (que esta declarada en el estado).,No sé por qué aparece este mensaje cuando intento hacer eso. ayuda

Comment: Daniel, esto es StackOverflow en español así que debes traducir tu pregunta. Te recomiendo leer [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y hacer [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del sitio y ganes tu primera medalla. Tambien te recomiendo leer [algunas razones por las que debes incluir el código en texto](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/182188) y no como imagen.

Comment: Oh ya veo. Gracias por el consejo. Editare mi post

Answer (score 1):

`Never` indica que el array siempre va a estar vacío.

Tienes que decirle a Typescript qué tipo de valor va a estar en el array del `state`.

Por ejemplo:

Array con string = `Array<string>` o `string[]`

Array con objetos = `Array<{id: number, texto: string}>`

Array con any = `Array<any>` o `any[]`

En tu código, por ejemplo:

```
state: {
carritoCompra: new Array<{id: number, nombre: string, precio: number}>(),
listaTienda: new Array<string>()
}
```